# Flatpak taking too much storage

Tags: storage, flatpak

When I run `flatpak list -d --app --runtime`

I see the following

```
… … … Version  Branch Arch   Origin  Installation Ref                                                  Active commit Latest commit Installed size …
… … … 19.08.10 19.08  x86_64 flathub user         org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08                893ea4aa41e3  -             694.1 MB       …
…  …          19.08  x86_64 flathub user         org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08     0d51f4a9d159  -             243.1 MB       …
…  …          1.4    x86_64 flathub user         org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-440-82/x86_64/1.4 d144b6da9032  -             984.1 kB       …
…  …          19.08  x86_64 flathub user         org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/19.08    febe88924fa8  -              37.0 MB       …
… … …          2.0    x86_64 flathub user         org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.0         15266352ca75  -             773.6 kB       …
… … …          3.36   x86_64 flathub user         org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.36                       ad7f022f9489  -             934.5 MB       …
… … …          3.22   x86_64 flathub user         org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Pop-dark/x86_64/3.22               01db4ce9aee6  -               1.6 MB       …
```

Why is flatpak consuming so much storage? And which files are safe to delete and how to do it?

**My system:**

`OS`:`Pop! OS 20.04lts`
`RAM`: 8GB
`CPU`: Intel i7-8750H
`GPU`: GTX 1050ti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since flatpaks are in a self-contained, (mostly) isolated environment, their applications use these runtimes to provide the libraries they need. If you want to check out what runtime(s) a particular app is using, run this (example for Calibre):

```
$ flatpak info com.calibre_ebook.calibre

Calibre - E-book manager

          ID: com.calibre_ebook.calibre
         Ref: app/com.calibre_ebook.calibre/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 5.0.1
     License: GPL-3.0
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: user
   Installed: 362.9 MB
     Runtime: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
         Sdk: org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/20.08

      Commit: 9dc73d95de91fd0798c3b7ed431f359edbcbb90ead9c8ce9e2658fd0bc2aa9ef
      Parent: e7491dda0dcfc6f3511d0282493ea45535555a1d3e26c6c36d6ec34c1b5ca482
     Subject: Update calibre-5.0.0-x86_64.txz to 5.0.1 (4bb0279f)
        Date: 2020-09-25 14:36:39 +0000
```

Now, as you remove unneeded flatpaks, the system is *supposed* to also clean up any unused runtimes. To check this, run:

```
$ flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Note: from what I've experienced, the biggest runtimes are KDE, Freedesktop (runtime/SDK), and Gnome. Also, if your / partition is getting to full, you can instead switch your flatpaks to your /home partition. This will require you to add the flatpak user repo, like this:

```
flatpak remote-add --user flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Then, install flatpaks are normal, but add the `--user` switch:

```
$ flatpak install --user flathub com.calibre_ebook.calibre
```